# Positive solution of system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Suppose, I have three ODEs 
$$ 
\dot{x} = f_1(x,y),\\
\dot{y} = f_2(x,y,z),\\
\dot{z} = f_3(y,z)
$$
where $x, y,$ and $z$ are function of $t$. Could you please provide the guideline, how to prove that the solution is always positive or condition for a positive solution for all values of $t$.

I need to know the guideline for the prove as well as if you can direct me to the resources/textbook to look for would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the context for which this problem appears in?

Comment: This is some problem in ecology. I need the general guideline for the proof.

Comment: Are you sure to have a system just as general as written?  Because in ecology it is natural to write a system of ODEs in the form $\dot{x}=x f_1(x,y)$, $\dot{y}=y f_2(x,y,z)$, $\dot{z}=z f_3(y,z)$.  In such a case, the property you are searching for is a consequence of the uniqueness of solution of the IVP (provided that the RHSs are sufficiently regular, which usually occurs in the ecology).

Comment: Incidentally, do you know the book *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*, CUP, 1998, by J. Hofbauer and K. Sigmund?

Comment: Thanks user539887. Is there any example available on internet? I don't have this book.

Comment: I am afraid that there are no examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vector field $F = (f_1, f_2, f_3)$ is sufficiently well-behaved (continuously differentiable is enough), then a sufficient condition is for the vector field $F$ to be pointing "away from" the negative parts of the space on the boundary between negative and positive. For example, if $f_3(x,y,z)>0$ whenever $z=0$, a solution to the ODE which starts with $z>0$ can never cross into the $z\leq0$ region.

You could look for worked examples of the [Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations), in which positivity is shown using this method.

If your vector field doesn't turn out to have this property, then you need more sophisticated arguments which will depend on your specific equations - this is a very broad question.

Comment: What part of the above example (Lotka-Volterra equations) tells that solution is always positive for all time t? Sorry for asking a very simple question.

Comment: @bell The Wikipedia page I linked to doesn't prove that the solutions are always positive. You would have to find another source proving that, but the point is you usually do that using the method I described in the first paragraph.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I understand the basic idea.